# python findall not finding the regex

Tags: python, regex

So I have a string: `data = "1234 5678 9012 3456"`
and I have regex: `(\S)+`
Which I confirmed matches `"1234", "5678", "9012", "3456"` with RegExr.

However when I do: `re.findall("(\S)+", data)` it returns `["4", "8", "2", "6"]`. 
Am I using re.findall incorrectly  to find `"1234", "5678", "9012", "3456"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No your regex is incorrect :

```
>>> re.findall("\S+", data)
['1234', '5678', '9012', '3456']
```

Answer (score 2):

The capturing group caused this:

```
re.findall("\S+", data)
```

works as expected.